# eclipse juno, how can I associate currently opened files with a project or am I using eclipse outside the box?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I have been using eclipse for a few years. I typically use just ONE workspace and have several projects for all of my perforce branches. I close the ones I'm not working on, open the one I am interested in.

The caveat to this approach is that I have to manually close empty editor tabs every time I do this.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

I'm really not a fan of having multiple workspaces as then I have to setup proejct variables for each new workspace.

Is there a way to associate the currently open set of editor tabs to the current project(s)?

Thank you for your time.

-Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to associate the currently open set of editor tabs to the current project(s)?

AFAIK, no. However, you can associate the editors to a task by using [Eclipse Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn). This way when you switch to an old task, it will set the editors and package exlorer to only show what you worked on the last time.

If you are working with defects from Jira or Bugzilla or a few other systems, these defects can automatically be imported into mylyn and will allow for very easy context switching.

If you dont get tasks from one of the supported repositories you'd have to manually create the tasks, but then just creating a dummy task for each project you work on would create the effect you are after.

Comment: I've never used Mylyn. Can it peacefully co-exist with the version control I use from www.perforce.com ?

Comment: Hmm ok so it appears that Mylyn isn't a version control. Shows what I know of it. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, at first it's a pita to use and can seem confusing. But if you use it regularly in the correct way the penny will drop in a few days and you'll see how good it can be. Atleast that was my experience.